# Efficient way to match regex patterns against huge volume of data

Tags: c#-4.0, io

I have 30 text files (say log files) and size of these files varies from 100MB to 200MB and I have got one more text file (Pattern.txt) which contains around 30 regex patterns. I need to compare all the regex patterns against each line in the log files in a fast and efficient way. Currently i am reading line by line from a log file and compare it against all the patterns.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this without using third party components?

Comment: Yes, there are quite a few ways to make it faster. I'll add an answer that works with most languages Ive dealt with..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When filtering don't use a regex ie if you need to compare line N with 30 regexes try and turn those regexes into string `indexof` operations ie is this string in this line if so then we compare the regex. Basic string comparison functions are incredibly fast, if performance with regex's is an issue use the normal string compare functions first to speed things up. The following example is a bit contrived but it demonstrates that filtering then using regexes is a lot faster than just using regexes.

```
index time: 3492  ms
regex time: 81553 ms
```

I created a file with 70Mb alternating lines in it ie

```
Value="Path=/this/is/a/path" InitString="Path = " EndString="," /> 
<Pattern Value="Path=/this/is/a/path" InitString="Path = " EndString="," />
```

Iterating over these line by looking for the string `Pattern`. The function that uses indexOf to filter the lines is for this use case 23 times faster (I'm not a C# developer so some of this might not be idiomatic).

```
private void indexOf(StreamReader streamReader) { 
  String line;
  string pat = @".*Pattern.*";
  Regex r = new Regex(pat);
  while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine ()) != null) { 
    if(line.IndexOf("Pattern") > 0) { 
      if(r.Match(line).Success) { 
        this.line_count++;
      } 
    } 
  } 
} 

private void regex(StreamReader streamReader) { 
  String line;
  string pat = @".*Pattern.*";
  Regex r = new Regex(pat);
  while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine ()) != null) { 
    if(r.Match(line).Success) { 
      this.line_count++;
    } 
  } 
}
```

You need to write your application in a way where it can first filter before using regular expressions.

Comment: "if you need to compare line N with 30 regexes try and turn those regexes into string indexof operations" Can you please elaborate a little ? i put one of my regex here    <Pattern Value="Path\s=\s((\w|[._-])+)+," InitString="Path\s=\s" EndString="," />

Comment: Thanks harry, nice answer.